# Clicar em um link ir para outra página e mostrar o id desejado

Tags: javascript, css, link

Bom, eu preciso fazer com que ao clicar em um link de uma página vá para outra e só mostre o conteúdo do id indicado na primeira página, tem como fazer isto? Procurei em vários lugares e não achei exatamente o que procuro.

**index.php**

```
<a href="interna.php" onclick="toggle_visibility('bloco1');"></a>
<a href="interna.php" onclick="toggle_visibility('bloco2');"></a>
```

**interna.php**

```
<div id="bloco1" style="display:none">
<div id="bloco2" style="display:none">
```

**Esse foi o javascript que usei**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>
```

**UPDATE**
Agora os blocos são exibidos mas quando eu vou para o segundo bloco todas as funcionalidades dos links(por exemplo botão voltar) não funcionam, somente o primeiro bloco funciona perfeitamente. Reparei que em todos os links o código insere interna.php?exibir=bloco1 por exemplo, não sei se é isto que está atrapalhando agora.

```
<a href="interna.php?exibir=bloco1"></a>
<a href="interna.php?exibir=bloco2"></a>

<script>

 function queryObj() {
    var result = {}, keyValuePairs = location.search.slice(1).split("&");
    keyValuePairs.forEach(function(keyValuePair) {
        keyValuePair = keyValuePair.split('=');
        result[decodeURIComponent(keyValuePair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(keyValuePair[1]) || '';
    });
    return result;
}
```

**carrega o conteúdo apos tudo ser renderizado**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
```

**chama o metodo para parsear a url**

```
    var objetoParaOcultar = queryObj();
```

**mostra a div com o id enviado por parametro**

```
    $('#' + objetoParaOcultar.exibir).show();
})
</script>
```

Comment: Modo de envio GET, amigão

Comment: Silvio Andorinha Não entendi o que vc quis dizer, não sou muito bom em javascript, poderia explicar?

Answer (score 2):

Na sua primeira pagina teremos os *links* na página conforme abaixo:

```
<a href="interna.php?exibir=bloco1">exibir 1</a>
<a href="interna.php?exibir=bloco2">exibir 2</a>
```

Já na sua segunda pagina, teremos o seguinte Javascript (lembre-se de importar o jQuery antes desse código):

```
<script>

   function queryObj() {
      var result = {}, keyValuePairs = location.search.slice(1).split("&");
      keyValuePairs.forEach(function(keyValuePair) {
          keyValuePair = keyValuePair.split('=');
          result[decodeURIComponent(keyValuePair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(keyValuePair[1]) || '';
      });
      return result;
   }

   /*carrega o conteúdo apos tudo ser renderizado*/
   $(document).ready(function () { 

      /*chama o metodo para parsear a url*/
      var objetoParaOcultar = queryObj();

      /*mostra a div com o id enviado por parametro*/
      $('#' + objetoParaOcultar.exibir).show();

      /*Remove os parametro da url após mostrar a div*/
      window.location.href.replace(window.location.search,'');
   });

</script>
```

Ele funciona da seguinte forma: A função "parseia" o parâmetro enviado pela sua URL e em seguida usa o mesmo para mostrar as `div`.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem o que vc fez, mas vou mostrar o que eu estava fazendo nesses horas depois que postei aqui. A ultima coisa que eu tentei fazer foi isto 
                  <a href="interna.php?id=bloco1" onclick="document.getElementById('bloco1').style.display='block';return false;">

Só que também não deu em nada, o ponto resumido é, que eu só preciso jogar um display:block no id referenciado do click e mostrar ele.
Pode ser em javascript ou jquery mesmo

Comment: aeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee muito bom, funcionou agora, vou ter que estudar aquela parte de KeyValuePairs, search, slice e split pq ainda não entendi muito bem a função delas. Mas vlw mesmo cara

Comment: Dando uma testada detectei um problema quando eu vou para o bloco2 todas as funcionalidades dos links dentro dela se perdem, por exemplo eu tenho um botão voltar e ele não funciona, mas no bloco1 funciona não sei pq. Os blocos são exatamente o mesmo só que só muda o conteúdo, por exemplo qualquer link fica mais ou menos assim interna.php?exibir=bloco1#cenario tipo quando qualquer link que está ali dentro não precisaria ter  interna.php:exibir=bloco1

Comment: Brunno - Vou fazer melhor vou disponibilizar um link para vc ver o que acontece. O link é este aqui http://twinshark.com.br/estatico/ , o problema é que quando vc clica no segundo thumb do portfolio ele mostra o conteúdo do bloco 2 só que perde toda a funcionalidade das outras coisas dentro bloco que tem #

Comment: Brunno - Primeiro obrigado pelo elegio, descobri o que acontece agora tem o menu ali em cima onde tem direção de vídeo, conceito de cenário e etc quando eu coloco o segundo bloco ele só funciona o primeiro por estar na mesma página sei que isso ja não tem haver com o post mas se vc puder ajudar, por que só funcionar perfeitamente com um bloco o menu

Comment: Brunno - Era isso mesmo man obrigado por tudo agora esta perfeito

Comment: Opa... favor setar o topico como resolvido... e grande abraço