# Executar uma função Javascript pelo link do site?

Tags: javascript, html

Exemplo tenho o link:

```
www.meusite.com.br/index.php?subject=conteudo do assunto;message=teste de mensagem
```

Quero chamar a função `onclick` desse botão automaticamente:

```
<input value="Enviar" tabindex="3" onclick="return submitThisOnce(this);" accesskey="s" class="button_submit" type="submit">
```

O que altero no link para chamar essa função de clique?

Segue a função:

```
function submitThisOnce(oControl)
{
    // Hateful, hateful fix for Safari 1.3 beta.
    if (is_safari)
        return !smf_formSubmitted;

    // oControl might also be a form.
    var oForm = 'form' in oControl ? oControl.form : oControl;

    var aTextareas = oForm.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
    for (var i = 0, n = aTextareas.length; i < n; i++)
        aTextareas[i].readOnly = true;

    return !smf_formSubmitted;
}
```

Comment: existe a função **submitThisOnce?** se sim então acho que se retirar o **return** já deve resolver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi sua pergunta, é possível fazer isso via JavaScript da seguinte forma:

```
function suaFuncao() {
    alert('sua função');
}

/*Pega o evento de Load da pagina*/
(function() {

    /*Pega a url atual*/
    var urlAtual = window.location.href;

    /*Seta a url para chamar a função*/
    var urlParaRedirecionar = 'www.seusite.com.br';

    /*verifica se é para execultar a função, se sim, ele a execulta*/
    if(urlAtual == urlParaRedirecionar) {
        suaFuncao();
    }

})();
```

Para não precisar comparar a url inteira, você pode passar um parâmetro via url dizendo que é para redirecionar, como nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80905/clicar-em-um-link-ir-para-outra-p%C3%A1gina-e-mostrar-o-id-desejado/80927#80927) :)

Comment: O problema é que não posso alterar a página

Comment: Meu amigo sem acesso a página, só via URL você não vai conseguir uma forma de fazer :, ( pois a URL é só sua ferramenta de navegação :( o que você pode fazer é criar uma extensão no Chrome para fazer isso pra você :)

Comment: Beleza, vou ser se o desenvolvedor muda lá

Comment: Beleza, se precisar de algo pode me chamar aqui =D

Answer (score 0):

Vamos colocar o exemplo completinho né, faltou sua função script ai, mas vamos supor ela aqui na resposta.

```
<input value="Enviar" tabindex="3" onclick="submitThisOnce(this);" accesskey="s" class="button_submit" type="submit">
<script>
function submitThisOnce( $input ){
// faz alguma coisa antes do submit
}
</script>
```

Há quem diz que o correto jé colocar **onclick="javascript:submitThisOnce(this);"** como funciona dos dois jeitos eu de preguiça escrevo sem o *javascript:*

Comment: Completei com a função.. Não entendi muito, eu não posso fazer nenhuma alteração no código da página, quero apenas manipula-la através do link o site.. Como no exemplo que coloquei no post, queria chamar/executar a função pelo link