# Como transferir dados de um arquivo javascript para outro em páginas diferentes?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um site simples, com duas páginas HTML cada uma com um código JavaScript vinculado:

**Primeira Página:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="primeiraPagina.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Segunda Página:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="segundaPagina.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Como eu consigo transferir dados de um arquivo script para o outro, por exemplo transferir o valor de uma variável da *primeiraPagina.js* para a *segundaPagina.js*, sem o uso de *frameworks*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso de duas maneiras, a primeira pode ser utilizando a [**sessionStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). Que salva os dados na sessão do *brownser* e expiram junto da mesma.

```
//Utilize esse comando para setar o valor na primeira
sessionStorage.setItem('dados', 1);
```

e

```
//Utilizar esse comando para recuperar os dados na segunda
sessionStorage.getItem('dados');
```

Você pode também pode passar esses dados pela url, conforme descrito nesse [**post**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80905/clicar-em-um-link-ir-para-outra-p%C3%A1gina-e-mostrar-o-id-desejado/80927#80927)

Comment: Bem na hora que comentei você mudou pra `sessionStorage`, hahaha. Essa mesmo que eu ia sugerir +1