# Passar parametro para uma segunda pagina html

Tags: html

Eu tenho uma pagina que contem 2 `textbox e um submit`, tenho uma outra pagina na qual seria a próxima que também tem 2 `text box com um submit`.

Como eu poderia fazer para que as informações digitadas na primeira pagina, ou seja, na `textbox`, adicione automaticamente no `textbox` da segunda pagina que ele vai direcionar e, se possivel, ele apertar o botao da segunda pagina após preencher o `textbox` com os dados da `textbox` anterior?

Comment: Passa por queryString e trate-as no `page load` da segunda página... :)

Comment: Podes explicar que tipo de conteúdo queres passar, a linguagem que tens no servidor, e porque razão não fazes isso na mesma página com conteúdo escondido?

Comment: de uma olhada nesse link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439463/how-to-get-get-and-post-variables-with-jquery

Comment: Acho que essa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/93825/30045) pode te ajudar, e [esta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90663/30045) tmb :)