# Passar valores de um formulário para o outro

Tags: html, formulário

Eu comecei a aprender código há pouco tempo e criei estes dois formulários em HTML, no qual preciso pegar os valores que foram preenchidos no primeiro formulário, e passá-los para o segundo.

Como posso fazer isso?

1º Formulário:

```
<html>
 <form>
  <head>
   <body>
    <table> 
    <tr>
     <td>
     <label>Quantidade de dados a serem replicados(MB):</label>
     </td>
     <td>
     <input type="text" name="qnt" id="qnt" />
     </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
   </body>
  </head>
 </form>
</html>
```

2º Formulário:

```
<html>
 <form>
  <head>
   <body>
    <table>
    <tr align="center">  
     <td align="left" style="width: 46%">Quantidade de dados a serem replicados(MB):</td>
     <td align="right" style="width: 22%" id="qnt"></td>    
    </tr>
    </table> 
   </body>
  </head>
 </form>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual seria a aplicação? Usando javascript, ou uma linguagem server-side? Dependendo da aplicação pode-se fazer de outra forma...

Comment: Tenho que fazer em javascript, porém estou aprendendo agira, não tenho muito conhecimento.

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso você terá que usar um pouco de JavaScript! Com ele você pode usar a [**sessionStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) (um recurso do HTML5) para te ajudar nessa tarefa. Vale lembrar que o mesmo ainda pode gerar um certo problema com *brownser* antigos:

Na primeira pagina você ira adicionar o seguinte código:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="qnt" id="qnt" />
<input type="button" value="Salvar" id="btn" />
```

Obs: adicionei um botão para ajudar a pegar o valor, mais pode ser usado o `keyup` do input text. E você também pode usar o `window.location` para te redirecionar após clicar no salvar =]

JavaScript:

```
(function() {

    var btnElement = document.getElementById('btn');
    var qtdElement = document.getElementById('qnt');

    btnElement.addEventListener('click', function(){
        sessionStorage.setItem('qtdMb', qtdElement.value);
    });

})();
```

Na segunda pagina você usará o seguinte código:

HTML (verifique seu HTML postado acima, ele está com a tag `html` alinha a uma `form`):

```
<table>
    <tr align="center">
        <td align="left" style="width: 46%" id="exibir">Quantidade de dados a serem replicados(MB):</td>
        <td align="right" style="width: 22%" id="qnt"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    var element = document.getElementById('exibir');
    var value = sessionStorage.getItem('qtdMb');
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + value;        
})();
```

Para ver funcionando, basta acessar esse [**jsfiddle1**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/n56a0ckL/) adicionar o valor, e na sequencia abrir esse [**jsfiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/fmgx5m44/) e ver o seu resultado. Obs: no jsfiddle usei a `localStorage` pois a `session` não da certo entre as paginas, mais o conceito é o mesmo a diferença é que uma gurda na sessão e a outra no brownser. Uma outra forma de fazer isso também é mandando sua informação via URL mais é um pouco mais trabalhoso e eu já respondi nessa [**pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80905/clicar-em-um-link-ir-para-outra-p%C3%A1gina-e-mostrar-o-id-desejado/80927#80927) :)